# Vagrant static ip problems in ubuntu/focal64

Tags: networking, static-ip, vagrant

I'm trying to start a a vagrant vm for a new project using image ubuntu/focal64. I want to have a static IP.

So here's my Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/focal64"
  config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.0.155"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = "2048"
  end
end
```

As simple as it gets. But it just can't configure the network. Here's the output:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu/focal64'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/focal64' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: jitsi_default_1598910502143_20427
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: bridged
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: 
    default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    default: 
    default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
    default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    default: your host and reload your VM.
    default: 
    default: Guest Additions Version: 6.1.10
    default: VirtualBox Version: 5.2
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
#<Thread:0x000056139b5db538@/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:71 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
    119: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in run'
    118: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:188:in `action'
    117: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:188:in `call'
    116: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:592:in `lock'
    115: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:202:in `block in action'
    114: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:227:in `action_raw'
    113: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    112: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    111: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    110: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    109: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    108: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
    107: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    106: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
    105: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    104: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    103: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    102: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    101: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    100: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
     99: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     98: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box.rb:56:in `call'
     97: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     96: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
     95: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     94: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
     93: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     92: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
     91: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
     90: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
     89: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
     88: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
     87: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     86: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
     85: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     84: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
     83: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     82: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/customize.rb:40:in `call'
     81: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     80: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/prepare_clone.rb:15:in `call'
     79: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     78: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_clone_snapshot.rb:17:in `call'
     77: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     76: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/import.rb:13:in `call'
     75: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/import.rb:74:in `import'
     74: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     73: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/discard_state.rb:15:in `call'
     72: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     71: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/match_mac_address.rb:19:in `call'
     70: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     69: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
     68: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     67: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
     66: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     65: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
     64: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     63: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_check_outdated.rb:79:in `call'
     62: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     61: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
     60: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
     59: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
     58: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
     57: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
     56: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     55: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
     54: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     53: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
     52: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
     51: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
     50: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
     49: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
     48: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     47: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
     46: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     45: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
     44: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
     43: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
     42: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
     41: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
     40: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     39: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
     38: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     37: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
     36: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     35: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clean_machine_folder.rb:17:in `call'
     34: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     33: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/set_name.rb:50:in `call'
     32: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     31: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clear_forwarded_ports.rb:15:in `call'
     30: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     29: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:80:in `call'
     28: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     27: from /home/nelson/.vagrant.d/gems/2.5.1/gems/vagrant-timezone-1.3.0/lib/vagrant-timezone/action/set_timezone.rb:13:in `call'
     26: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     25: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/env_set.rb:19:in `call'
     24: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     23: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_forwarded_port_collision_params.rb:30:in `call'
     22: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     21: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:49:in `call'
     20: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     19: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_nfs_valid_ids.rb:12:in `call'
     18: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     17: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/synced_folders/nfs/action_cleanup.rb:25:in `call'
     16: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     15: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced_folder_cleanup.rb:28:in `call'
     14: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     13: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced_folders.rb:87:in `call'
     12: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
     11: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_nfs_settings.rb:19:in `call'
     10: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
      9: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clear_network_interfaces.rb:26:in `call'
      8: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
      7: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/network.rb:134:in `call'
      6: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/guest.rb:43:in `capability'
      5: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/capability_host.rb:111:in `capability'
      4: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/capability_host.rb:111:in `call'
      3: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/guests/debian/cap/configure_networks.rb:31:in `configure_networks'
      2: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/guests/debian/cap/configure_networks.rb:153:in `configure_nettools'
      1: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:267:in `sudo'
/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:257:in `execute': The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. (Vagrant::Errors::VagrantError)
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

/sbin/ifdown 'enp0s8' || true
/sbin/ip addr flush dev 'enp0s8'
# Remove any previous network modifications from the interfaces file
sed -e '/^#VAGRANT-BEGIN/,$ d' /etc/network/interfaces > /tmp/vagrant-network-interfaces.pre
sed -ne '/^#VAGRANT-END/,$ p' /etc/network/interfaces | tac | sed -e '/^#VAGRANT-END/,$ d' | tac > /tmp/vagrant-network-interfaces.post
cat \
  /tmp/vagrant-network-interfaces.pre \
  /tmp/vagrant-network-entry \
  /tmp/vagrant-network-interfaces.post \
  > /etc/network/interfaces
rm -f /tmp/vagrant-network-interfaces.pre
rm -f /tmp/vagrant-network-entry
rm -f /tmp/vagrant-network-interfaces.post

/sbin/ifup 'enp0s8'

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

bash: line 4: /sbin/ifdown: No such file or directory
sed: can't read /etc/network/interfaces: No such file or directory
sed: can't read /etc/network/interfaces: No such file or directory
bash: line 18: /sbin/ifup: No such file or directory
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

/sbin/ifdown 'enp0s8' || true
/sbin/ip addr flush dev 'enp0s8'
# Remove any previous network modifications from the interfaces file
sed -e '/^#VAGRANT-BEGIN/,$ d' /etc/network/interfaces > /tmp/vagrant-network-interfaces.pre
sed -ne '/^#VAGRANT-END/,$ p' /etc/network/interfaces | tac | sed -e '/^#VAGRANT-END/,$ d' | tac > /tmp/vagrant-network-interfaces.post
cat \
  /tmp/vagrant-network-interfaces.pre \
  /tmp/vagrant-network-entry \
  /tmp/vagrant-network-interfaces.post \
  > /etc/network/interfaces
rm -f /tmp/vagrant-network-interfaces.pre
rm -f /tmp/vagrant-network-entry
rm -f /tmp/vagrant-network-interfaces.post

/sbin/ifup 'enp0s8'

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

bash: line 4: /sbin/ifdown: No such file or directory
sed: can't read /etc/network/interfaces: No such file or directory
sed: can't read /etc/network/interfaces: No such file or directory
bash: line 18: /sbin/ifup: No such file or directory
```

After that I tried to change to auto_config: false:

```
config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.0.155"
```

and follow [these](https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-setup-static-fixed-ip-on-ubuntu-20-04-18-04/) instruction on how to set a static IP manually, which lead to the machine to hang. If I try to edit the file as instructed and reload the VM, it stops on ssh configuration indefinetly:

```
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/focal64' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: bridged
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key << stops here and doesn't continue
```

How do I set a static IP on vagrant's ubuntu/focal64 image ?

The host OS is Mint 19.3.

**Edit** Answering @sarnold:

After it hangs if I try to ping it the ping response is this:

```
nelson@whateve:~/dir$ ping 192.168.0.155
PING 192.168.0.155 (192.168.0.155) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.14 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.14 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.14 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.14 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.14 icmp_seq=8 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.14 icmp_seq=9 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.14 icmp_seq=10 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.14 icmp_seq=11 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.14 icmp_seq=14 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.14 icmp_seq=15 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 192.168.0.155 ping statistics ---
16 packets transmitted, 0 received, +10 errors, 100% packet loss, time 15347ms
pipe 4
```

**Workaround**

I found a workaround: use bento/ubuntu.20-04 box. It's working fine.

**Edit2**

I found that this is a known bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/vagrant/+bug/1893705
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vagrant/+bug/1738400

Using the workaround has a problem: It does work. It sets the correct IP and you can use this IP in the development environment to access the application. Yet it does this by creating another interface. So you get a eth0 with a 10.0.2.15/24 IP and eth1 with 192.168.0.155/2. I just need 192.168.0.155 ip. So ideally I would prefer eth0 configured with 192.168.0.155 ip and no eth1.

If anyone knows how I can do this it would be very helful

At the moment my configuration is this:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-20.04"
  config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.0.155", auto_config: false
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = "2048"
  end
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    # My VM configuration
  SHELL
  config.vm.provision "shell", run: "always", inline: <<-SHELL
    ifconfig eth1 192.168.0.155 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
    route add default gw 192.168.0.1
    eval `route -n | awk '{ if ($8 ==\"eth0\" && $2 != \"0.0.0.0\") print \"route del default gw \" $2; }'`
  SHELL
end
```

I choose the manual configuration as I was trying to remove eth0 without success. But if you remove auto_config: false, and the run: always provision it does the same thing.

Comment: Does it respond to pings? What would you expect the next output line to be? Do other VMs on this machine work fine or is it all VMs?

Comment: Does it respond to pings? - see edit; What would you expect the next output line to be? don't know; Do other VMs on this machine work fine or is it all VMs? This is my develpment workstation, all VMs work, but this is the first time I'm setting up a 20.04 vm. Thanks for your help.